# How to replace the server in an appium mobile app functional test?

Tags: xamarin, mocking, functional-testing

We have been writing our mobile app tests with Calabash/Xamarin.UITest for a while using backdoor methods to redirect our app's base api url to a mock HTTP server to make tests repeatable without incurring unnecessary server costs.

As Xamarin has announced they are phasing out Calabash (and Xamarin.UITest with it, as it relies on the Calabash server component) we have been working on migrating our test suite to Appium to comply with Xamarin's recommendations. Our simpler tests were migrated easily but a lot of our testing relies on said mock HTTP server with backdoor configuration which Appium does not seem to support, rendering our tests impossible to port without a way to recompile our app with the mock HTTP server address built in, which quite frankly, sucks.

Anyone knows an alternative to said backdoor method? Or an alternative to the whole mock HTTP server overall?

We want our tests to run in parallel in the Xamarin Test Cloud service so issuing a QA/Test environment for this is completely undesirable.

Comment: Do you have a link that states Microsoft/Xamarin are deprecating / phasing out Calabash support?

Comment: @SushiHangover Received this mail a couple days ago from Xamarin: https://pastebin.com/raw/mejP8Gf3 - Slack link https://hockeycamp.slack.com

Comment: Thanks for the copy of the email.... As far as a "backdoor", I've worked with several clients using `Appium` (plus Calabash and others) and what we have done is within a `Settings` panel in the app (Droid Preference Fragments or iOS Settings bundle), development settings can be accessed via a two-way challenge pin entry... within those sub-settings you can "reset/init" a database, change API endpoints, enable logging levels, capture app state, etc... and save or clear those settings for future app runs... Then you can automate the those settings in a UI test or work with a remote app user

Comment: @SushiHangover Spoke to a Xamarin engineer on that Slack channel and he told me the mail was poorly written. Only the Calabash/Ruby combo is being phased out, with UITest support still going on strong so we chose to migrate our tests to UITest instead, due to the similarity to the Calabash syntax and API.

Comment: @SushiHangover Regarding that debug panel suggestion we've decided it's not that worth it and it'd only add development time. We do see the value for more manual QA approaches but we're not focusing on that for now. Thanks though, much appreciated :)